# How do I extract a specific directory from a tarball? and strip a leading directory?

Tags: tar

I want to extract a specific directory from the wordpress tarball. specifically `wp-includes` to  `.`. It appears that the directory structure inside the tarball is `wordpress/wp-includes` but I just need`./wp-includes` once it's been extracted, no leading wordpress directory. How would I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To extract a specific directory (and its contents, recursively), just pass it as an extra argument on the command line. With [GNU tar](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html), you can strip a leading directory with the `--strip-components` option (and more generally transform the file names with `--transform`). On non-Linux systems, you can use [pax](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html) (it's in POSIX, but some Linux distributions omit it from their default installation) and its `-s` option.

```
tar xf foo.tar --strip-components=1 wordpress/wp-includes  #GNU tar
pax -r <foo.tar -pp -s '!^wordpress/!!' wordpress/wp-includes
```

You can merge the inclusion list with the rewriting rules by appending a rule to rewrite everything to the empty name (which means “don't extract”; the rule only applies if the previous rules didn't match).

```
pax -r <foo.tar -pp -s '!^wordpress/\(wp-includes/\)!\1!' -s !.*!!
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have GNU tar, you can use [`--strip-components`](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/transform.html):

```
$ tar xaf tarball.tar.gz --strip=1 wordpress/wp-includes
```

I believe current versions of BSD tar also support `--strip-components`.  In the worst case, you could do:

```
$ tar xzf tarball.tar.gz wordpress/wp-includes
$ mv wordpress/wp-includes .
$ rmdir wordpress
```

Comment: I ended up doing the latter just because in a hurry, but good to know the former exists.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a command that doesn't require explicitly naming the stripped component (e.g. `wordpress`)? I need this when I'm extracting GitHub created tarballs which contain the git revision in the stripped component which I don't know in advance.